# NestJs doesn't work in "watch" mode inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs

I am trying to use NestJs inside Docker. For the first run 'docker compose up --build' it works good, all changes in files force application to rebuild. But if I stop docker with 'docker compose down' and then 'up' it again - application stops to react on any changes. Sometimes, it gets stuck on the command 'nest start --watch'.
I tried almost everything, but only purging all docker data helps to make it work again until another 'down'. If I remove volumes, it works, but it doesn't see any file's changes. What should I do to make it work?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    build: .
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - nodemodules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_NAME}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata:
  nodemodules: {}
```

scripts from package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

Comment: can you try with npm run watch-poll, i wrote this because i dont see package.json and you run start:dev, but after having watch-poll, instead of watch would work on docker-compose with volumes

Comment: I added scripts from package.json, there is no watch-poll command:(

Comment: What OS is your host machine? There are some issues with Windows/WSL2 where file change notifications don't get sent to the container properly.

Comment: It is macOS Big Sur

Comment: Solved be reinstalling Docker application

Comment: @skob maybe this video will help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLqlCkvAKKQ

Answer (score 4):

try to add `watchOptions` to your tsconfig.json file.
it even solved my issue with a windows host

When you're using the NestJS CLI to start your application in watch mode it is done by calling tsc --watch, and as of version 4.9 of TypeScript, a new strategy for detecting file changes is used which is likely to be the cause of this problem. In order to fix this problem, you need to add a setting to your tsconfig.json file after the "compilerOptions" option as follows:

```
  "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "fixedPollingInterval"
  }
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly